# Which book on a deserted planet with a maze and an insane ancient creature?

Tags: story-identification, books

I want to identify the author of a book.

The plot: A spacecraft lands, possibly forced, on an otherwise deserted planet where there are ancient ruins of a high-tech civilization. A centerpiece is a great maze. The crew making their way through the maze are subjected to a variety of deadly encounters with fantastical beasts. It turns out that there is a great deal of illusion in the encounters - things are not what they seem. The resolution of all of this is that there is a lone survivor from the ancient civilization that is thousands of years old - it is a black oily creature, large, and rather like an octopus. It has psychic powers. It has gone mad from loneliness. Near the end of the book, someone manages to attack the creature directly with fire, it burns and is killed.

The book is not by Andre Norton. It occurs on an otherwise deserted planet and does not involve any interplanetary intrigue. It is not set on Mars. It does not have parallel worlds. It does not occur on multiple planets. It is a simple story about a the small crew of a spacecraft that lands on this planet and finds an ancient psychic black octopus creature that is the last survivor of its race and has gone insane through loneliness. It dies in a fire at the end of the book.

The style of the book is similar to but less sophisticated than Andre Norton. The black octopus creature is just a small single creature on a single planet. It has gone insane with loneliness and is not the Vom of Dean Foster. It controls only the maze - which is the remains of the city it used to live in.

So far the suggestions have been not really on target. I provide a lot of information here in this post, and have added some. The crucial point is that some of the respondents are insisting on not believing me about the basic plot. I recall many of the details well. What I cannot do is find this book in a Google search - especially since there are so many books with similar titles and with mazes and with ancient civilizations.

The title of the book was "the devil planet" or that with minor grammatical variations. Unfortunately, there are several books with this type of title. And this has misled lots of respondents.

It is not any of the following:

- "The Devil's Planet" by David Wright O'Brien
- "Devil's Planet" by Manly Wade Wellman
- "Who Fears the Devil" by Manly Wade Wellman
- "Satan's World" by Poul Anderson
- "Devil's Planet" episode of *Space 1999*
- That episode of *Doctor Who*.
- Lucifer rising, etc.

It is certainly dated earlier than 1980, perhaps than 1970. It could be earlier. It was science fiction, of course. I found a copy in a second-hand bookshop in 2004, in New Zealand, which enables me to confirm some of the details. I skim read some of it, and the ending. I regretted not grabbing it at the time - it was gone a few hours later.

The cover of the 1970s book was, I believe, blank - the separate dust cover having been lost. The cover of the book I saw in 2004, which was a small format paperback and less than 200 pages, leaves only a vague impression in my mind, but it was predominantly reddish and showed an image of a couple of people in coveralls.

It is a kids' book. (about 10 to 13 years old)

The planet is unknown and unexplored, and otherwise deserted, and the antagonist is the last remaining member of an ancient race of psychic beings and dies in a fire. It is not a galactic force. These elements are the strongest in my memory.

[image: very rough sketch of the cover]

I include here a very rough sketch of the cover - the people were running toward the camera, so to speak. The drawing was a lot better, of course. This just gives the basic configuration. The drawing was done in a realistic sketch style. On the cover there are only two and only two figures (unless perhaps something tiny in the background, but I don't think so). They are wearing practical clothes (no bird-headgear) And there is not much if any background.

Comment: Taken as a whole the description makes me think of Andre Norton, but I can't think of a specific book that matches.  Forced landing on a planet with ruins matches many of her books, like *Star Guard*, *Exiles of the Stars* and *Forerunner: The Second Venture*, etc.; dealing with illusionary dangers is in *Voodoo Planet*, *The Ice Crown* and others...

Comment: @user14111 Wade Wellman's book seems to bare no particular resemblance to my description.

Comment: @DavidW There is a commonality of style with Andre Norton, although it is less sophisticated, that suggests the Solar Queen, or the Zero stone. But also the The Tar-Aiym Krang which was not Norton. I think is was a common theme from 1950 to 1980. But I would guess c1960.

Comment: "*"**The Devil's Planet" by David Wright O'Brien**. Cardigan and Bennett had developed a helluva business. It was a lucrative mining operation for vardium on the distant planet of Igakuro. Little did they suspect, though, that they were being targeted by a band of interplanetary pirates. The pirates' leader, a merciless outer space thug named Satan, had plans of taking over their entire operation-and he didn't mind using an atomic pistol and taking a few lives in doing it. Making things even more complicated was the arrival of a space missionary and his beautiful daughter"*

Comment: ***The Devil's Planet by Manly Wade Wellman's** combines an adventure story set on Mars with a locked room murder mystery. Dillon Stover lands on Mars with a mission to continue his grandfather's work to bring a sustainable water supply to the parched planet, but before he knows it he finds himself accused of murder and on the run.*

Comment: @PonderStibbons If you're going for Alan Dean Foster (*The Tar-Aiym Krang*) then I have to note the Vom, which is ancient and evil and described as black and fluidly protean, from *Bloodhype*.

Comment: Can you by chance remember what the cover looks like? Either the one you read originally or the one you saw later, if they are different.

Comment: @DavidW okay, thanks for bring up the Vom, which this creature definitely is not. I have added that on the list of misfires in the main post.

Comment: You seem pretty certain about the title but on the off chance it might be misremembered I've been searching for sf novels that feature mazes. Take a look at Masters of the Maze by Avram Davidson. The plot does not seem a good match but the cover image on wikipedia seems close to what you describe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_of_the_Maze_(novel)

Comment: @skyjack I looked that up and it says parallel worlds. So, sadly, not it. One thing I see in the various attempts at this is that all the suggestions so far have too much intrigue etc. The story I am after is a story of a lone ship landing on an unremarked planet that turns out to have a mad psychic alien on it - who dies. No plotting, just an unfortunate and isolated encounter with no deeper meaning.

Comment: @PonderStibbons out of curiosity take a look at this question which I posted. I am looking for a very similar story  but mine I think is not the one you are after, but it might jog some additional memories... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237346/short-story-id-astronauts-use-hover-bikes-to-traverse-alien-maze

Comment: That sketch is a very close match for one version of the cover for the Manly Wade Wellman novel(la).

Comment: Here's a link to the Amazon listing: https://www.amazon.com/Devils-Planet-Manly-Wade-Wellman/dp/1605437913

Comment: @ZeissIkon thanks for the link. For my money, that is not similar. It is a man and a robot standing, not two men running, and they are both at the same distance. But, it is interesting to see different covers.

Answer (score 5):

[image: A cover of The Man in the Maze, the title in green letters on a yellow background, below that a man in green clothes running along a pathway or bridge of some sort, looking back at a hovering spherical droid, many similar pathways in the background]

I think I know the book you're looking for cause I've read something similar when I was a child, although it was not a kids book. It was from my grandpa's collection.

It's *The Man in the Maze* by Robert Silverberg.

I searched for the plot just to be sure. And it follows:

> The main character is Richard Muller, a retired diplomat who is forced to hide from the human race on the planet of Lemnos. He lives there in the center of an ancient city-maze, built by a vanished race. The outer zones of the maze are filled with lethal traps to discourage entrance intro the central zone.

As I said, I don't think its a kids book cause it's more centered on the philosophy of the meaning of life and the search for *something* meaningful. But it may be the one you're looking for, I hope!

(The book has a lot of [different covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?14914), cause it was serialized before the whole content was made into a book, so you can find a lot of pictures)

This one is from the May 1968 issue of *[If](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_(magazine))* and looks quite a bit like the description given ("predominantly reddish and showed an image of a couple of people in coveralls").

[image: The cover of the May 1968 issue of Worlds of If, that contains the second part of The Man in the Maze, with two man in white coveralls wearing helmets with a visor that covers their eyes, one of them carrying a weapon, with a black shilouet of a rocket ship in the distance, all on an orange background]

Comment: I thought of this one too, with the deadly maze full of both traps and illusions.  However, there's also a lot that doesn't seem match the question at all.

Comment: I don't see the oily black insane psychic creature in this; the monster at the centre of the maze is Muller.

Comment: I have to say that I didnt find any cover that matches the book I read as a child. Maybe it was made only for the Portuguese release. So the New Zealand may be a different one as well. Also there is a LOT of creatures in this.

Comment: having re-read the question I notice that he says it was a kids book. Really dont think Man in the maze was aimed at kids or young adults, but thanks for having a go at finding it.

Comment: The Man in the Maze has originally 192 pages, as he remembers it was 200 or so.

Comment: Not it, but I appreciate the point. One thing that I do not know is whether the title on the NZ copy was the same as the other. Sometimes these things change title (eg the silver locusts vs the martian chronicles). One thing I have tried to emphasize is that this is a single ship on an isolated and unremarked planet and the whole had no connection to any other tangled plots by anyone.

Comment: I've edited the picture to the one that seems more likely to be the right one.

Comment: @valorum Yes, the location of the person is about right, as per my sketch.

Comment: @PonderStibbons, [this cover of _The Worlds of If](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/1/16/WOFIFMAY1968.jpg)_ that contains the second part of Silverberg's _The Man in the Maze_ seems a good match for your description of the cover: reddish background, two men in coveralls.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a book which matches the cover and kind of matches the title, but doesn't match the plot.  Is it possible that you are mixing up elements of two different books?

*Witch World* (1963) by Andre Norton has a Portuguese title of *Mundo Diabólico*.  I don't speak Portuguese, but isn't that *Devil World*?

The cover is also quite similar to your sketch

[image: Front cover of Witch World with two men in the foreground, approaching]

Comment: I've seen that cover many times, and that hat never fails to make me laugh.